# What is a classifier in Python (Gaussian Naive Bayes)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, naivebayes

okay so when I use the following code, what exactly does that "clf" part mean? is that a variable? I know that's a classifier but is classifier a function in python or it's just a variable named that way or what exactly? I am new to python and programming well. 
thanks already!

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
clf = GaussianNB()
```

Comment: It's just a variable name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB.html):

> [GNB] can perform online updates to model parameters via partial_fit method

Example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [-3, -2], [1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 2]])
>>> Y = np.array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2])
>>> from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
>>> clf = GaussianNB()
>>> clf.fit(X, Y)
GaussianNB(priors=None, var_smoothing=1e-09)
>>> print(clf.predict([[-0.8, -1]]))
[1]
>>> clf_pf = GaussianNB()
>>> clf_pf.partial_fit(X, Y, np.unique(Y))
GaussianNB(priors=None, var_smoothing=1e-09)
>>> print(clf_pf.predict([[-0.8, -1]]))
[1]
```

What is a classifier, one may ask? According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_classification), a classifier is

> an algorithm that implements classification, especially in a concrete implementation, is known as a classifier. The term "classifier" sometimes also refers to the mathematical function, implemented by a classification algorithm, that maps input data to a category.